# routes.rb is not defined correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two controllers: Tasksadmins and Workers.

I defined two roots, but someone told me that there is a problem with it.

can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
TODOLIST::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :tasksadmins
  root to: "tasksadmins#index"

  resources :workers
  root to: "workes#index"
end
```

Comment: The documentation is pretty thorough http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root` doesn't mean the `index` action of a controller. Instead, it means essentially the home page: what action gets called when I go to `http://www.example.com/`?

Therefore, it only makes sense to define one `root`: right now, you're pointing `http://www.example.com/` to both `tasksadmins#index` and `workers#index`, which doesn't make much sense. Rails will just pick one of them, but that's probably not the behavior you're looking for.

I suspect you're trying to refine your `resources` routes, but there's no need: `resources :workers` already defines the route `http://www.example.com/workers` pointing to `workers#index`, so that line should be all you need for the workers.

If, however, you want `http://www.example.com/` to point to the same workers listing as `http://www.example.com/workers`, then `root 'workers#index'` is exactly right.

Answer (score 3):

The `root` method of the routing DSL allows you to define the default route for the application or a specific namespace: you can't have multiple "root" routes.

The default route for a resource (e.g. `/workers`) is routed to the index action of the corresponding controller (`WorkersController`), there is no need to specify it per controller.

If you use the `root` method multiple times, the last occurence will be used. Here it will be `workers#index`. Simplify your routes :

```
TODOLIST::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: "workers#index"

  devise_for :users

  resources :tasksadmins
  resources :workers

end
```